# KeyError on relation field in Django-REST

Tags: django, foreign-keys, many-to-many, django-rest-framework, keyerror

I have the following models:

```
class ProductColor(models.Model):
    color_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class BasicProduct(models.Model):

    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    product_desc = models.TextField()
    product_price = models.FloatField(default=10.0)

    # Describes what colors are available for this product
    product_colors = models.ManyToManyField(ProductColor)

class BasicCartItem(models.Model):
    cart_product = models.ForeignKey(BasicProduct)
    cart_color = models.ForeignKey(ProductColor, blank=True, default=None, null=True)
```

And my ModelSerializer:

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.BasicCartItem
```

I'm giving my view this input:

```
{'cart_product': 1}
```

Then running the code:

```
    m = CartSerializer(data=inputdata)
    if m.is_valid():
        items = m.data # Generates KeyError: u'cart_color'
```

Extract of stacktrace:

```
  File "python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 430, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 103, in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 69, in get_attribute


  instance = instance[attr]
KeyError: u'cart_color'
```

Anyone with good knowledge knows what's going on here? I've been stuck here for hours and I don't know what I'm doing wrong..

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing `default=None` in your `cart_color` ForeignKey. That's unnecessary to have there, and it's probably causing your problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are accessing the data in a wrong way. You should **access `.validated_data`** on the serializer instead of `.data`.

```
m = CartSerializer(data=inputdata)
if m.is_valid():
    items = m.validated_data # access validated data here
```

**Why `serializer.data` approach did not work for your case?**

When you are doing `.data`, the serializer will try to serialize the `initial_data` as you have not passed the `instance` argument. It will expect all the fields to be present but since `cart_color` is not present on the data, it will raise a `KeyError`.

**When should you generally use `serializer.data` then?**

You should generally use `serializer.data` when you are serializing an existing object. This would require you to pass an `instance` argument when creating an instance of the serializer.

```
m = CartSerializer(instance=my_object)
items = m.data # use .data when serializing an object
```

Comment: Great answer! And how can I serialize the validated_data back to JSON? Now I get a "is not JSON serializable" if I try to JSON().render() it. @Rahul Gupta

Comment: You can use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) to serialize the validated data to JSON. For your case, `json.dumps(items)` would give you JSON formatted string.

Comment: It didn't work since validated_data contains django model instances, which gave . I had to use initial_data to have my JSON data back. dumps() gives the "<Basic Product> is not JSON serializable".

Comment: Please post the `inputdata` and `validated_data`.

Comment: Input: {'cart_product':1}
validated_data: OrderedDict([(u'cart_product', <BasicProduct: RedBlueProduct>)]). initial_data is working fine though!

Comment: We know that `.is_valid()` performs deserialization i.e. stream of native datatypes is parsed into a dictionary of validated data. Now in a  `ForeignKey` field deserialization, the reference object is returned. So, `.validated_data` is containing the object.  You can't directly convert that to json. If you just need to convert the id of that object to json, you can do that as per your approach. But, if you want to serialize the `cart_product` object, i think you would have to write a `BasicProductSerializer` which would give a serialized representation of `cart_product` object.